# Deserializing Microsoft.Graph objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, json-deserialization

I use Microsoft.Graph apis in my app. I make a request and get back the json data. But I am really confused trying to deserialize it.
E.g. for this json:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.scheduleInformation)",
  "value": [
    {
      "scheduleId": "jsmith@company.com",
      "availabilityView": "000000002022000",
      "scheduleItems": [
        {
          "isPrivate": false,
          "status": "busy",
          "subject": "Standup",
          "location": "Microsoft Teams Meeting",
          "isMeeting": true,
          "isRecurring": true,
          "isException": false,
          "isReminderSet": true,
          "start": {
            "dateTime": "2023-08-30T13:00:00.0000000",
            "timeZone": "UTC"
          },
          "end": {
            "dateTime": "2023-08-30T13:30:00.0000000",
            "timeZone": "UTC"
          }
        } 
      ],
      "workingHours": {
        "daysOfWeek": [
          "monday",
          "tuesday",
          "wednesday",
          "thursday",
          "friday"
        ],
        "startTime": "08:00:00.0000000",
        "endTime": "17:00:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": {
          "name": "Eastern Standard Time"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "scheduleId": "onetwo@company.com",
      "availabilityView": "000000000000000",
      "scheduleItems": [],
      "workingHours": {
        "daysOfWeek": [
          "monday",
          "tuesday",
          "wednesday",
          "thursday",
          "friday"
        ],
        "startTime": "08:00:00.0000000",
        "endTime": "17:00:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": {
          "name": "Eastern Standard Time"
        }
      }
    }    
  ]
}
```

I created a class for the root object:

```
public class ScheduleInformationRootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("@odata.context")]
    public string ODataContext { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public List<ScheduleInformation> Value { get; set; }
}
```

Maybe Microsoft.Graph has already such a class, but I could not find it. If it exists, please let me know.
So I tried to deserialize like this:

```
ScheduleInformationRootObject outlookScheduleInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ScheduleInformationRootObject>(responseJson);
```

But this gives me an exception:

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Error converting value "08:00:00.0000000" to type 'System.Nullable`1[Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions.Time]'. Path 'value[0].workingHours.startTime', line 1, position 1344.'

I also tried to deserialize using another library:

```
        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true // Enable case-insensitive property matching
        };

        ScheduleInformationRootObject outlookScheduleInfo = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ScheduleInformationRootObject>(responseJson, options);
```

This gives me another exception:

The JSON value could not be converted to System.Nullable`1[Microsoft.Graph.Models.FreeBusyStatus]. Path: $.value[0].scheduleItems[0].status | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 248.

In this case, it cannot convert the string value of "status" field to an object of class FreeBusyStatus.

I can re-write Microsoft.Graph's classes, but it doesn't seem to be the right approach.

I noticed that class ScheduleInformation has

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The deserialization information for the current model
    /// </summary>
    public IDictionary<string, Action<IParseNode>> GetFieldDeserializers() {
        return new Dictionary<string, Action<IParseNode>> {
            {"availabilityView", n => { AvailabilityView = n.GetStringValue(); } },
            {"error", n => { Error = n.GetObjectValue<FreeBusyError>(FreeBusyError.CreateFromDiscriminatorValue); } },
            {"@odata.type", n => { OdataType = n.GetStringValue(); } },
            {"scheduleId", n => { ScheduleId = n.GetStringValue(); } },
            {"scheduleItems", n => { ScheduleItems = n.GetCollectionOfObjectValues<ScheduleItem>(ScheduleItem.CreateFromDiscriminatorValue)?.ToList(); } },
            {"workingHours", n => { WorkingHours = n.GetObjectValue<Microsoft.Graph.Models.WorkingHours>(Microsoft.Graph.Models.WorkingHours.CreateFromDiscriminatorValue); } },
        };
    }
```

But cannot figure out how this should be used.

Comment: Do you use Graph SDK? How do you call the endpoint? When using Graph SDK you can avoid creating your own models.

Comment: Using SDK could solve your issue, you might install Microsoft.Graph

Comment: @user2250152 I do use it, but the problem is that I get the exceptions I described when try to deserialize using MS Graph classes.

Comment: @DavidShochet Ok, I will share my sample how to get schedule by another way.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my sample code：

```
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var users = await graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();
var tokenRequestContext = new TokenRequestContext(scopes);
var token = clientSecretCredential.GetTokenAsync(tokenRequestContext).Result.Token;
var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users")
            {
                Headers =
                {
                    { HeaderNames.Authorization, "Bearer "+ token}
                }
            };

 var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
 var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
 var res = "";
 if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
 {
      res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(res);
      var userList = obj.value;
      List<User> rr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(userList.ToString());
  }
```

I test with API "list users", so the response is like screenshot below, and convert to object, then getting the users, and finally convert to JSON string and `List<Microsoft.Graph.User>`

[image]

You are trying to get ScheduleInformation instead of user, so you should have code below instead.

```
var scheduleList = obj.value;
List<ScheduleInformation> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ScheduleInformation>>(scheduleList.ToString());
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't see how that would help me, as I am having issues deserializing ScheduleInformation object.

Comment: sorry I just showed a sample, what I used is a list users api, so the response is `Microsoft.Graph.User`, in your scenario, you are trying to get ScheduleInformation, so it should be [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-getschedule?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#response-1) and what  you get should be a list of [Microsoft.Graph.ScheduleInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/scheduleinformation?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: so you should use `var scheduleList = obj.value;
                List<ScheduleInformation> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ScheduleInformation>>(scheduleList.ToString());`

Comment: This gives the same deserializing exception. The problem is that ScheduleInformation class does not correspond to the json returned by the api.

Comment: sorry, since I don't have the test result, so I couldn't test in my side. But using SDK is the only way to have a out-of-box model for graph APIs, if the `ScheduleInformation` class didn't match the result of the json, then we don't have any other ways. By the way, I don't think such mistakes should be made in APIs,  I'm not questioning you, I just think the API might be improved if they donnot match with SDk...

Answer (score 0):

I would use `GetScheduleRequestBuilder` and call `PostAsync` method. It returns `GetScheduleResponse` with the `Value` property of type `List<ScheduleInformation>`

Create a new instance of `GraphServiceClient`. Azure.Identity nuget package is required.

Examples how to use different auth providers are [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/tokencredentials.md)

1. authentication through an interactive browser prompt

```
string[] scopes = {"your_scope"};
    
InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions interactiveBrowserCredentialOptions = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions() {
                    ClientId = clientId
    };
InteractiveBrowserCredential interactiveBrowserCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(interactiveBrowserCredentialOptions);
    
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(interactiveBrowserCredential, scopes);
```

2. Authentication with client secret

```
string[] scopes = {"https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"};

ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret); 

GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
```

```
var requestBody = new GetSchedulePostRequestBody
{
    StartTime = DateTime.Now.ToDateTimeTimeZone(),
    EndTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(8).ToDateTimeTimeZone()
};
var getScheduleResponse = await graphClient.Me.Calendar.GetSchedule.PostAsync(requestBody);
var scheduleInfos = getScheduleResponse.Value;
```

The code is for the [endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-getschedule?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request) `POST /me/calendar/getSchedule`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I have difficulty sending request like this (authentication issue). I use _httpClient.SendAsync(), and get json result without problem. All I need help with is deserializing.

Comment: I don't see in your code any deserializing.

Comment: @DavidShochet My idea was to avoid custom deserialization. I believe that resolving authentication error is better than trying to create custom json converters (it will be a challenge)

Comment: I don't understand how I can get requestAdapter in var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(requestAdapter);

Comment: And BTW I use a mobile app, which can give additional limitation, I think.

Comment: @DavidShochet I've updated the answer with two examples how to use auth providers and with the link to the doc. Agree that a mobile app can be limitation.

Comment: Got an error that I expected: "ClientSecretCredential authentication failed: Confidential client and managed identity flows are not available on mobile platforms and on Mac.See https://aka.ms/msal-net-confidential-availability and https://aka.ms/msal-net-managed-identity for details."

Comment: @DavidShochet If you already have a code to get a token, what about using custom [authentication flow](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#authentication). Implement custom `IAccessTokenProvider` and create `new GraphServiceClient(new BaseBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider(new CustomTokenProvider()));`

Comment: If I am not mistaken, it is also not for mobile apps