# Where is the instance of ISerializer in Microsoft.Graph API version 5.*

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, deserialization

I have a working version of application which uses Microsoft.Graph API version 4.37. Now upgrading it to use latest version 5.*.
The main updated/refactored code parts are working using dedicated request builders like:

```cs
var multipleEvents = (await graphClient.Me.Calendar.CalendarView.GetAsync()).Value;
var singleEvent = await graphClient.Me.Calendar.Events["Id of event"].GetAsync();
```

But there is a situation when I need to select different events by their IDs using Batch request. HttpRequests of type Get (by URL of event) are added to batch and  multiple response contents streams in version 4.* were parsed using:

```cs
var eventX = graphClient.HttpProvider.Serializer.DeserializeObject<Event>(jsonFromResponceContent);
```

But Serializer is gone in version 5.*. I can't find neither by Googling neither using JetBrains dotPeek.

Anybody knows where is it hidden?

Comment: The question is, why do you need it? you can use many libraries for deserializing JSON to a model.

Comment: do you think using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` is an option for you? I have a [test](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77014755/14574199) before.

Answer (score 2):

Batches are already supported from the library and you don't have to use manual serialization (which can't be done, cause the Graph SDK uses Kiota for serialization and not STJ directly). To make a batch in 5.* you can take a look at the [upgrade guide](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#batch-requests):

Apart from passing instances of `HttpRequestMessage`, batch requests support the passing of `RequestInformation` instances as follows.

```cs
var requestInformation = graphServiceClient
                         .Users
                         .ToGetRequestInformation();

// create the batch request
var batchRequestContent = new BatchRequestContent(graphServiceClient);
// add one or more steps (up to 20, or check below)
var requestStepId = await batchRequestContent.AddBatchRequestStepAsync(requestInformation);

// send and get back response
var batchResponseContent = await graphServiceClient.Batch.PostAsync(batchRequestContent);

var usersResponse = await batchResponseContent.GetResponseByIdAsync<UserCollectionResponse>(requestStepId);
List<User> userList = usersResponse.Value;
```

Find failing responses (and retry)

```cs
var statusCodes = await batchResponseContent.GetResponsesStatusCodesAsync();
// all the responses are successfull?
var allReponsesSuccessFull = statusCodes.Any( x => !BatchResponseContent.IsSuccessStatusCode(x.Value));
// the responses with a 
var rateLimitedResponses = statusCodes.Where(x => x.Value == (HttpStatusCode)429);
// maybe retry those rate limited?
var retryBatch = batchRequestContent.NewBatchWithFailedRequests(rateLimitedResponses);
var retryResponse = await graphServiceClient.Batch.PostAsync(retryBatch);
```

Automatically manage batch size with `BatchRequestContentCollection`.
The sample above uses the `BatchRequestContent` which has a limit of max. 20 combined requests. This means you'll need to manage the batch size yourself if you go beyond the batch limit of 20 requests.

Comment: Thanks, Oliver, I was already thinking that I need to refactor our inner batchManager class to handle not a stream from batchResponseContent.GetResponseStreamByIdAsync()) and then to Deserialize in batchMmanager's implementation, but to use a new method I have missed before - 

batchResponseContent.GetResponseByIdAsync<TIetem>(itemCallback.Key) which returns a deserialized TItem or List<TItem> instance.

Answer (score 1):

As @Oliver's response with a guidance to use

```cs
T response = await batchResponseContent.GetResponseByIdAsync<T>(requestStepId);
```

was very helpful, but my friend [Boris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4055383/bor1ss) by analyzing Graph API methods found the exact answer to "***how to get NATIVE deserializer?***"

```cs
var node = ParseNodeFactoryRegistry.DefaultInstance.GetRootParseNode("application/json", jsonFromResponceContent);
var item = node.GetObjectValue<Event>((_) => new Event());
```

Hope this will help somebody too.